# insert values from txt toan 2-demensions array or Arraylist using c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am new in programming and want some help with this.

I have to read a fixed length txt file, and to insert two values form each line in a two dimension array  or arraylist. I think that the best choise is the   a dynamic array...

I have read the relative topics but it;s not clear to me yet...

Could give me some help please.

Thank you in advance!

I cannot attach any code as I'am out of office know...

Answer (score 0):

In order to read a text file line by line:

```
using (var file = File.OpenText("foo.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // line will contain the current line being read
    }
}
```

Then you could use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to hold the data being parsed from each line.

Comment: First of all Darin thank you for the reply. I read the text exactly as you say . My question is , lets say that i want string x and string y from each text line then i how can i insert in list or an array this two strings . array isn't better ???